# Get working alpha value of scatter points in mpl_toolkits.basemap.Basemap

Tags: python, matplotlib, alpha, matplotlib-basemap

Building upon an example from [here](https://peak5390.wordpress.com/2012/12/08/matplotlib-basemap-tutorial-plotting-points-on-a-simple-map/), I'd like to plot points on a map with different alpha values as well as different facecolors (I plan to update them).  However, the alpha values do not seem to update (they seem ignored in the first place too).

First, create a map and plot three points, as per the example:

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

map = Basemap(projection='merc', lat_0 = 57, lon_0 = -135,
    resolution = 'h', area_thresh = 0.1,
    llcrnrlon=-136.25, llcrnrlat=56.0,
    urcrnrlon=-134.25, urcrnrlat=57.75)

map.drawcoastlines()
map.drawcountries()
map.fillcontinents(color = 'lightgray', zorder = 0)
map.drawmapboundary()

lons = [-135.3318, -134.8331, -134.6572]
lats = [57.0799, 57.0894, 56.2399]
x,y = map(lons, lats)
pts = map.scatter(x, y, c ='r', marker = 'o', s = 80, alpha = 1.0)
```

[image: First figure]

Then update the facecolors with new rgba values.

```
pts.set_facecolor([(0.7, 0.3, 0.3, 1.0), (1, 0.0, 1, 0.5), (1.0, 1.0, 0.2, 0.2)])
fig.canvas.draw()
```

[image: Second figure]

The colors update but the alpha values do not plot correctly.  I've tried using `pts.set_alpha` also but this doesn't allow a list as an argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, [after posting this as an issue on github](https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap/issues/276), it seems alpha values can be updated if you do not set the alpha value in the first place.

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
matplotlib.interactive(True)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

map = Basemap(projection='merc', lat_0 = 57, lon_0 = -135,
    resolution = 'i', area_thresh = 0.1,
    llcrnrlon=-136.25, llcrnrlat=56.0,
    urcrnrlon=-134.25, urcrnrlat=57.75)

map.drawcoastlines(zorder = 0)
map.drawcountries(zorder = 0)
map.fillcontinents(color = 'lightgray', zorder = 0)
map.drawmapboundary(zorder = 0)

lons = [-135.3318, -134.8331, -134.6572]
lats = [57.0799, 57.0894, 56.2399]
x,y = map(lons, lats)
pts = map.scatter(x, y, c ='r', marker = 'o', s = 600)
```

[image: figure 1]

And these alpha values can be updated by using `set_facecolor`, like so:

```
pts.set_facecolor([(0.7, 0.3, 0.3, 1.0), (1, 0.0, 1, 0.5), (1.0, 1.0, 0.2, 0.2)])
fig.canvas.draw()
```

[image: figure 2]

Comment: Thank you @p-robot. This halped me solve my problem (toggling points on/off on scatter plot).

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear if you can set the alpha value for each point separately but if you use multiple plot command it works.

```
pts = bmap.scatter(x[0], y[0], c ='b', marker = 'o', s = 80, alpha = 0.7)
pts = bmap.scatter(x[1], y[1], c ='g', marker = 'o', s = 80, alpha = 0.3)  
pts = bmap.scatter(x[2], y[2], c ='r', marker = 'o', s = 80, alpha = 0.5)
```

[image: Map with different alpha values]

Comment: This does not work for me.  The alpha values are unchanged.  For instance, try setting them to 1:

`pts = map.scatter(x[0], y[0], c ='b', marker = 'o', s = 80, alpha = 1)`
`pts = map.scatter(x[1], y[1], c ='g', marker = 'o', s = 80, alpha = 1)`
`pts = map.scatter(x[2], y[2], c ='r', marker = 'o', s = 80, alpha = 1)`

Comment: What about setting them to 1? Using alpha=1, it looks like figure 1 now.

Comment: Thanks.  However, with alpha=1 you can still see the coast line underneath, so it's not really alpha=1.  I'd like the points to have different alpha values too.