# How to toggle points on and off on matplotlib 3D scatter plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

SOLVED (see below)

On **2D** matpotlib scatter plot I can turn on and off points by accessing `_offsets` property of scatter plot object and setting it's `.mask` attribute True/False for indexes of those points we want to show/hide like this:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Button
import random


def TogglePoints(event, plot):
    plot._offsets.mask = [ [1, 1], [1, 1], [1, 1], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0] ]
    plot.figure.canvas.draw()


x = [random.randint(-10, 10) for n in range(6)]
y = [random.randint(-10, 10) for n in range(6)]
ax = plt.axes()
sc = ax.scatter(x, y, marker='o', s=20, alpha=1)
ax_button = plt.axes([0.81, 0.01, 0.1, 0.05])
button= Button(ax_button, "Toggle")
button.on_clicked(lambda event: TogglePoints(event, sc))
plt.show()
```

When you click the "Toggle" button on the figure, points with indexes 0, 1, 2 will disappear. You can make them re-appear by setting `_offsets.mask` back to False and re-drawing plot.
This is what I want to achieve with matplotlib **3D** scatter plot.

Using `_offsets.mask = [ [1, 1], [1, 1], [1, 1], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0] ]` on 3D scatter plot doesn't seem to work.
Actually it alters type of underlying array from MaskedArray to numpy.ndarray for some reason (see: [Numpy MaskedArray in matplotlib 3D scatter plot, turns into ndarray when called by PyQt5 button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70726399/numpy-maskedarray-in-matplotlib-3d-scatter-plot-turns-into-ndarray-when-called)).
I know that 3D scatter plots have `_offsets3d` property. However I don't know how I can use it to show/hide points on the plot. Or maybe there's some other way ?

Does anyone know how I can do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to this post:

[Get working alpha value of scatter points in mpl_toolkits.basemap.Basemap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35759581/get-working-alpha-value-of-scatter-points-in-mpl-toolkits-basemap-basemap)

I've found a workaround that serves my purpose.
It concerns setting alpha values of points with `set_facecolors()`.
So the working code now looks like this:

```
...
import pandas as pd #added

def TogglePointsOFF(event, plot):
    for n in range(3): # n = index of point
        fc_colors[n, 3] = 0 # 4th value is alpha
    plot.set_facecolors(fc_colors)
    plot.figure.canvas.draw()

def TogglePointsON(event, plot):
    for n in range(3): # n = index of point
        fc_colors[n, 3] = 1 # 4th value is alpha
    plot.set_facecolors(fc_colors)
    plot.figure.canvas.draw()

#I've put it into DataFrame() so you can better see
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['label'] = ["data_"+str(n) for n in range(6)]
df['id'] = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]
['x'] = [random.randint(-10, 10) for n in range(6)]
['y'] = [random.randint(-10, 10) for n in range(6)]
['z'] = [random.randint(-10, 10) for n in range(6)]
colors = {1:'red', 2:'blue'} # to map colors with df 'id'

#plot points colored according to value of df['id']
ax = plt.axes()
sc = ax.scatter(df['x'], df['y'], df['z'], c=df['id'].map(colors), marker='o', s=20, depthshade=False)
global fc_colors #yeah yeah globals...
face_colors = sc._face_colors
ax_button = plt.axes([0.81, 0.01, 0.1, 0.05])
ax_button_1 = plt.axes([0.68, 0.01, 0.12, 0.05])
button= Button(ax_button, "OFF")
button_1= Button(ax_button_1, "ON")
button.on_clicked(lambda event: TogglePointsOFF(event, sc))
button_1.on_clicked(lambda event: TogglePointsON(event, sc))
plt.show()
```

Clicking buttons "ON" and "OFF" will hide/show group of points based on index.

I've tried using `set_alpha()` and passing iterable of alpha values like: `[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]` however it seemed to work on random points and set alpha of incorrect points.

Also getting face_colors from `get_facecolors()` seemed to get colors with random index alignment. This may be connected why passing iterable with alpha values to `set_alpha()` didn't work. That's why I take colors of points from: `sc._face_colors` .

Thank you for your time.

WARNING! Be advised.

This doesn't work when you use any 'official' colormap like this:

`sc = ax.scatter(df['x'], df['y'], df['z'], cmap='tab10, vmin=10, vmax=10, marker='o', s=20, depthshade=False)`

For setting alpha of points as described above you have to "kind-off" make you own colormap mapping like it was done here:

`c=df['id'].map(colors)`

or, use Normalizer object to map any colormap to some custom values like this:

```
from matplotlib.colors import Normalize #added

#let's assume we have some score values coresponding with data points:
score = [random.uniform(0.101, 100.123) for n in range(6)]
#but we can use any iterable with numbers

norm = Normalize(min(score), max(score)
cmap = matplotlib.cm.get_cmap('Spectral') #get some built in colormap
colors = cmap(norm(score))
#now you can use colors as 'c' parameter:
sc = ax.scatter(df['x'], df['y'], df['z'], c=colors, marker='o', s=20, depthshade=False)
```

Remember! don't put any alpha parameter and use depthshade=False to prevent fading of points in the back of the plot.

I hope you found this usefull.
Keep scrolling.